# Searching for posts with tags using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing an API using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I have a database containing posts, tags, and the many-to-many mapping between them. I want to look up posts that have at least one matching tag in a search. For example, a search for tags "A", "B", and "C" should return posts that have "A" or "B" or "C" as their tags.

I am roughly following [Charles Leifer's example](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/a-tour-of-tagging-schemas-many-to-many-bitmaps-and-more/) of querying multiple tags when using a many-to-many relationship. My current query, however, does not return any rows at all:

```
@app.route('/api/posts/search', methods=['GET'])
def search_posts():
    tags = json.loads(request.data['tags'])
    posts = db.session.query(Post).join(TagMap).join(Tag).filter(Tag.tag in tags).group_by(Post.id).all()
    return jsonify(posts)
```

I have confirmed that the tags enter the database correctly as a list of strings, and that I have posts, tags, and the mapping between them correctly stored in the database.

If necessary, my models are as follows:

```
@dataclass
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id:int
    text:str
    created:str
    op:bool

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    text = db.Column(
        db.String(2000),
        index=False,
        nullable=False
    )

@dataclass
class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id:int
    tag:str

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    tag = db.Column(
        db.String(32),
        index=False,
        nullable=False,
        unique=True
    )

@dataclass
class TagMap(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tagmap'
    post_id:int
    tag_id:int

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    post_id = db.Column(
        db.ForeignKey('post.id'),
        index=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    tag_id = db.Column(
        db.ForeignKey('tag.id'),
        index=False,
        nullable=False
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like it's an issue with your `in` check. You currently have:

```
Tag.tag in tags
```

Which will be first evaluated in Python to a boolean value. Which will always be `False` because `Tag.tag` is not a string, and so can never be "in tags". This effectively generates a `WHERE 0 = 1` (may differ depending on DB) in your SQL query.

You need to use [the "SQL-in"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_) by rewriting it as:

```
Tag.tag.in_(tags)
```